No Email Contacts in "All Contacts" for Child BU in SFMC
Within a Child Business Unit, only MobilePush contacts are visible in the "All Contacts" section of Contact Builder. Email contacts are not appearing, despite having a significant number of email subscribers listed in "All Subscribers."
In the Parent BU, all contacts, including email subscribers, are correctly displayed in both "All Contacts" and "All Subscribers."
There is a Business Unit filter configured in Email Studio (Admin section) for the Child BU, which is intended to restrict visibility to the relevant data for this BU. The filter appears to be set up correctly, so it's unclear why email contacts are missing from "All Contacts" in the Child BU.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwEyAAK/all-contacts-does-not-display-all-channels-or-sources-when-business-unit-filters-are-enabled

I would suggest reviewing this KI

Contact Builder does not currently support BU Filtering. If access to these sections are needed in Contact Builder, remove the BU Filter if possible.

